# Swipe Left Gesture not working correctly. UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I am using a swipe gesture on a UITableView. I am trying to perform actions on a TableViewCell when it is swiped left. I noticed the correct cell is swiped, but for some reason it seems to activate a random other cell.

I am suspecting it has something to do with the pointer? I am not very good with memory pointers, so any help would be great. The code that handles the swipe is:

```
- (void)handleSwipeLeft:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    // Get location of the swipe
    CGPoint location = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.requestTableView];

    // Get the corresponding index path within the table view
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.requestTableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:location];

    // Check if index path is valid
    if(indexPath)
    {
        //Get the cell out of the table view
        requestCell *cell = (requestCell *)[self.requestTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        NSLog(@"%@", [cell.IDLabel text]);


        cell.sendingImage.hidden = false;
        cell.activityIndicator.hidden = false;
        cell.requestorLabel.hidden = true;
        cell.dueDateLabel.hidden = true;
        cell.IDLabel.hidden = true;
        cell.priorityImage.hidden = true;     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling "cellForRowAtIndexPath" will most probably not give you that instance of the cell that is currently visible on the screen. UITableView is (if correctly used) based on cell reuse - which means, every time "cellForRowAtIndexPath" is called, the table view will try to find an unused cell and if there is none, create a new one.
In your case that means, that the cell you perform the swipe gesture on is NOT the same cell as you get when calling the cellForRowAtIndexPath-method when handling the swipe. Instead, a currently not used instance of your cell type is returned and you perform your changes on that instance.
One way to solve this problem would be, not to change the cell's properties directly in the gesture handler, but make changes to the data model that is used to fill the cell and then call `tableView reloadCellAtIndexPath...`to refresh the cell.

Comment: Should be a fairly simple hypothesis to test: add some code to log the location, and swipe the same cell at several different scroll positions. Also swipe a few different cells scrolled to the same on-screen location.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I will think on manipulating the data model directly. I did however do a log on what cell is swiped. It does return the right cell I swiped. The action does perform fine on the swiped cell, but for some reason it also causes another cell that is not on screen to have changed state to being swiped. Thanks you for the input!

Comment: Perhaps then the issue is that you're not fully resetting the content of the cell when it's reused? @Steffan Blass is correct that this happens. If your code (as shown) only manipulates the cell's state when swiped, what happens when you scroll the table? (That cell will go out of view, and then be re-used for a different index path....)

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should subclass UITableViewCell and add the swipeGesture directly to the cell.
Just an idea. Haven't thought it through though.